# php file_get_contents() shows page instead of html source code

Tags: php, html

I've got this piece of code, which should fetch the source code of the website.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://homepage.com');
echo $homepage;
```

Instead of actually giving me the source code.. It's shows me the page that I'm trying to get the source code from.

Comment: Have a look on the page source and think for a second

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either use `htmlentities` or change the content type.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://homepage.com');
echo htmlentities($homepage);
```

or

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://homepage.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

Comment: May I ask what you're intending to do with the fetched HTML code? If you want to display the code on a web page with other content/design or you want to drop it into a textarea on a form, then you'll need to use `htmlentities`. If you set the header, then you won't be able to display anything else on your resultant page other than text, because it's basically doing the same thing as taking a page called `index.html` and renaming it to `index.txt` -- it won't be parsed as code anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [**htmlspecialchars**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://homepage.com');
echo htmlspecialchars($homepage);
```

Comment: the htmlspecialchars didn't do the job for me. Thanks for taking your time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're fetching the source code and (re)outputting it. Your page is just mirroring `http://homepage.com`.

To see the actual page source, add a `Content-Type` header before your `echo` statement:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

This tells the browser treat the source as plain text and not interpret it as HTML.

Comment: This works well for me as well. Thanks! But, i'm wondering if there is any solution to display the html code as well as php code if that web page has php code in it? Just curios! Because i created a simple login website. Afraid that there is any solution can view the php code i have in the page. So that people can easily hack the login details.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are printing the source, your browser will interpret that as a webpage. To see the actual code use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($homepage);
```