# Get Url Source Html with enabled JavaScript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, bash

I know that this question allready has answer, but, that's not my case. I try to download the source of a webpage that is javascript enabled. The problem is that I found a solution that works from bash but not from PHP. 
Here is the commands(methods) I've tried so far:
1. PhantomJS
Running directly command from bash works:

```
phantomjs get.js 'https://someurl.com/'
```

Running `exec`(and `shell_exec`) from php the same comand does not return the full web page but only a part of web page with a warning that "This webpage requires JavaScript..."

```
$command = "phantomjs get.js '".$url."'";
$string = shell_exec($command);
```

I've also tried to call a bash script from php that runs this command also without success.

```
$command = "sh t1.sh '".$url."'";
$string = shell_exec($command);
```

And again the same story..running directly command `sh t1.sh 'https://someurl.com/` returns the full web page but calling from php not.

I've also tried Lynx with the same result:

```
$command = "lynx -source '".$url."'";
$string = shell_exec($command);
```

Above code return's a part of page that say's that javascript is required and this one works:

```
~]# lynx -source 'https://someurl.com/'
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838785/php-file-get-contents-shows-page-instead-of-html-source-code

Comment: thanks for help...that was my mistake...I was passing the wrong url format.